# fingerprinting entire iPhone music library with echoprint

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, data-cleaning, audio-fingerprinting

I'm wondering how intensive it would be to fingerprint an iphone 4+'s entire music library with echoprint. how long should I expect it take to analyze 2-3k songs? Is this even reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the library the code runs faster than real time (it is said 20% of real time). I hope it answers your question